# PHP ODBC INSERT does not work - no errors

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc

Why it doesn't work? I have no errors, but the result is nothing as well.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
$data_from_client = isset($_POST["data"]) && strlen($_POST["data"]) ? $_POST["data"] : null;
// Database path
$db = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
$db = str_replace("php/insert_query.php", "data/users/testuser.accdb", $db);
// Connect
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=$db; Uid=; Pwd=;");
// INSERT data
$count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO posts(username, date) VALUES ('Matthew', '2015')");
// echo the number of affected rows
echo $count;
// close the database connection
$dbh = null;
```

}

Comment: Add this prior to the `exec()` call and see what happens:  `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: I get two empty errors. I don't understand why. I have read a lot of solutions, but one didn't work either.

Errors:

http://s11.postimg.org/53uf524yr/Image_1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the nature of your error:

```
try {
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO posts(username, date) VALUES ('Matthew', '2015')");
    echo $count;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getCode() . '|' .$e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My program are working very well now. I took a huge mistake, when I gave the "date" name for a column in Microsoft Access Database.